# handle http errors in rxjs lastValueFrom

Tags: rxjs

I have started to use the lastValueFrom() to handle my observable http requests. One of these http calls is returning an error from the server-side, and I am getting the  `name: 'EmptyError', message: 'no elements in sequence'` message

```
const response = await lastValueFrom(
        this.service.doStuff()
    ).catch((e) => {
        console.log('#1', e);
        return {} as DoStuffResponse;
    });
```

at #1 the error is *EmptyError* , not the error from the http call.

I understand why I am getting it (the http observable does not return a value)

However, what I'd like to know is what the *actual* error is (a 422 unprocessable entity in this case)

Is this possible ?

Comment: Are you using Angular's http service? Then you can use `this.http.get(/* you_url */, { observe: 'response' })`

Comment: I'm using a service that I believe internally uses angular http, but I can't modify the service

Comment: Then you're out of luck I'm afraid.

Comment: Can we see `service.doStuff()`? If an observable throws an error, then `lastValueFrom` will resolve with an error too. I would guess that `doStuff` is trying to handle that error itself and when it fails, it just completes. If this is what is happening, then you've got to handle this differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not found a method to catch the Http errors from lastValueFrom and this does not appear to be documented in rxjs.

As a result I've decided to avoid lastValueFrom when doing Http requests.  Instead I stick with Subscribe and always get the Http response codes in the error.

As an aside, many people noticed Subscribe as being deprecated in VSCode, but this is not true; just a certain overload.  I know you didn't mention the deprecation as a motivator for using lastValueFrom, but I think most people, including myself, used the VSCode deprecation alert as a prompt to switch.

That said, this Subscribe syntax is still valid and should give you the Http error code:

```
this.someService.getResults.subscribe(
{
  next: (results) => {
    console.log('Here are the results...', results);
  },

  error: (err: any) => { 
    console.log('Here is the error...', err.status);
  },
  complete: () => { }

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You do actually have the possibility to gracefully catch errors from `lastValueFrom` like this:

```js
firstValueFrom(this.http.post(url, body))
.catch((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
  console.log("error: ", error);
  return "an error has occured"
}).then(response => {
  // In case of an error this will receive "an error has occured" as a response
  console.log("resp: ", response)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with NestJS.
The solution was to wrap it in a try/catch clause:

```js
 async myFunctionOrMethod(
    myPayload: any
  ): Promise<Result<Response, Err>> {

    try {
      const result = await lastValueFrom(
        this.httpService.post('/api/endpoint', { myPayload})
      );
      return Ok(result.data as Response);
    } catch (err) {
      return Err(new InternalServerErrorException(err));
    }

  }
```